# Does $ x \notin (A\ominus B)\ominus C $ imply $ x \notin A\ominus B \ominus C $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read a proof for the following statement:
$ x \in (A\cap B)\setminus C \Rightarrow x \notin A \ominus B \ominus C $

$ \ominus = $ symmetric difference

Here is the proof:

$ x \in (A \cap B)\setminus C \Rightarrow x \in A \land x\in B \land x \notin C $. Therefore, $ x \notin (A \ominus B)$. Hence, $ x \notin (A\ominus B)\ominus C $.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

However, I don't understand why $ x \notin (A\ominus B)\ominus C  $ implies $ x \notin A\ominus B \ominus C $. Aren't these different sets?

Comment: Doesn't associativity mean $ (A \ominus B)\ominus C  = A \ominus (B \ominus C) $?

Comment: Oh, missed what you wrote. What do you think $A\ominus B\ominus C$ means, if not $(A\ominus B)\ominus C?$

Comment: In general, if $\star$ is a binary operation, $A\star B\star C$ is ambiguous. But when the operation is associative, the two possibilities are equal, so we don’t include the clarifying parentheses.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you, thought it meant $ (A \cup B \cup C) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C) $

Comment: Yeah, that isn't what it means. That would mean symmetric difference isn't a binary operation, but a bunch of different $n$-ary operations.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same set. **XOR** is associative (other than brute force checking, note that XOR is the addition operation in the finite field with two elements). Hence since $A \ominus B$ is the set of all elements in $A$ *xor* in $B$, it will also be associative. Thus,

$$(A \ominus B) \ominus C = A \ominus B \ominus C.$$

Indeed, there isn't a well-defined *meaning* to the right-hand expression without associativity.